# Jquery :contains showing alert for all span

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

I have a span `<span style="font-weight: bold;">Text goes her</span>` like this

```
$('#contentarea').bind('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                if($(e.target).is('span')){
                    if($(e.target).find(":contains(font-weight: bold;)")){{
                         alert('bold');
                    }
                }
            });
```

i am not getting the actual result, if i click any span text it will alert,please help me, i need to find out the span contains the **font-weight: bold;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the attribute selector...(if you just need to select the span containing the style attribute as font..)

try this

```
$('span[style^="font-"]')
```

this should select the span with style starting with `font-`

or

```
$('span[style="font-weight: bold;"]')
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MtTAR/)

Comment: if($(e.target).is('span[style^="font-weight:"]')){
     $('.btn-group').find('a[title="Bold"]').addClass('active');alert('ok');
    } but it is not showing the button active, it is coming and going not setting.trying to do while the bold text clicking the bold button will be activate

Comment: i am trying to make a button(Bold) is selected, while click on the bolded texts in the contentarea. using the bootstrap

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/naveenbos/tKC8k/ please check this, i have a button but it is not showed in the jsfiddle, i need to change the button class to activate when clicking on the bold text.

Comment: that is actually working... check this fiddle for example http://jsfiddle.net/tKC8k/1/

Comment: Bad luck for me, the class btn changing but it is going, not setting their

Comment: are you using bootstrap for this ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$(e.target).find(":contains(font-weight: bold;)")
```

It always returns a jQuery collection of objects - including 0 length collection. This is not a javascript list and you always get `true` in boolean.

```
var target = $(e.target);
if(target.is('span')){
     if(target.css('font-weight') == 'bold'){
         alert('bold');
     }
}
```

Comment: i need to process, if a bold is detected in the span, then what will do for getting the exact result

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var isBold =$(e.target).css('font-weight');
if($(isBold === ("bold")|| isBold === 700){
                         alert('bold');
                    }
```

This way you check for existence of CSS properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a heads up, the `:contains()` selector is for the **content of the DOM node**, so you  could use it with the following HTML:

```
<div id="contentarea">
    <span>Hello World</span>    // will alert when clicked
    <span>Goodbye World</span>  // will not alert when clicked
</div>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('#contentarea').bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(e.target).is('span')){
        if($(e.target).is(':contains(Hello)')){
            alert($(e.target).text());
        }
    }
});
```

What you're trying to do is look at the **applied CSS styles**, or an **attribute**, so you would want to do something more like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="contentarea">
    <span style="font-weight: bold;">Hello World</span>
    <span style="font-weight: 700;">Hello World</span>
    <span>Hello World</span>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#contentarea').bind('click',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(e.target).is('span')){
        if($(e.target).css('font-weight')==="bold" || $(e.target).css('font-weight')==="700"){
            alert($(e.target).text());
        }
    }
});
```